# Who formulated this Generalized Lotka-Volterra model?

Tags: references, growth-model, differential-equations

In the introduction of this paper

[Bifurcations in a predator–prey model with general logistic
growth and exponential fading memory](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2016.12.003)

The authors claim

[image]

I didn't know that this model was well known.

Can anyone point to a general reference where this model is formulated and perhaps studied?

Comment: I think this question belongs on [biology.se] as it is not about statistics at all. Moreover, have a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/icesjms/3.1.3), as many popular generalisations of Lotka–Volterra are in fact by Volterra.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Perhaps Mathematics, but if sent to Biology, it will just be buried as too technical ...

Comment: *Too technical* is not a valid close reason on Biology. And it has a [very similar question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88674/5403) (unclosed) already. But yes, [math.se] might also work.